# Regarding development of comparator

Tags: java

I have a Query I have developed a pojo ..

```
public class Customer {
int Age;
public Customer(int age, String surname, String forename) {
    super();
    Age = age;
    Surname = surname;
    Forename = forename;
}


String Surname,Forename;

public int  getAge() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Age;
}

public String getSurname() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Surname;
}


public String getForename() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Surname;
}



 public void display()
 {
  // System.out.println(Forename+"\t"+Surname+"\t"+Age);
     System.out.println(Age+"\t"+Forename+"\t"+Surname);
  }
```

}

and here is my collection class ..

```
    class testCustomerComparator
{

    public static void main(String... a)
    {

            Customer customerFirst = new Customer(46,"Alabama", "Christonson");
        Customer customerSecond = new Customer(21, "Anna", "Sobek");
        Customer customerThird = new Customer(27, "Rafael", "Sobek");

        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        list.add(customerThird);
        list.add(customerSecond);
        list.add(customerFirst);
}
}
```

please advise me How to make comprator for this class , I want to make comparator so  that  a list of customers get  sorted  by age and second by surname. After that you want to sort by forename. please advise I have nesting condition inside comparator

lOGIC MUST BE SOMETHING LIKE...

```
   public class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {

    if (c1.getAge() == c2.getAge()) {
      if (c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname()) == 0) {
          return c1.getForename().compareTo(c2.getForename()) {
      } else {
          return c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname());
      }
    } else if (c1.getAge() > b2.getAge()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
  }
```

but it is not working please advise

Answer (score 1):

Seems much like homework. I can give you some hints in where to look at.

You have two choices:

- make the POJO class extend `Comparable<Customer>`
- define a custom external comparator as a `Comparator<Customer>`.

Assuming the second choice, in which you have two explicit customers, you'll have to define a method similar to this one:

```
@Override
public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2)
{
  // this method should return 0 if c1.equals(c2), 
  // should instead return 1 if c1 should come first than c2 and -1 otherwise
}
```

Comment: If you're using Java 1.6 or above, it's probably worth annotating the `compare` method with `@Override` so you'll get a compile time error if your method doesn't implement the appropriate method signature.

Comment: oconnor0: you've got the 1 and -1 mixed up.  The contract says this:  "a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."  It's worth noting that "negative integer" and "positive integer" rather than being exactly -1 and 1.  I suppose this is for easy comparison of numeric values (simple subtraction, rather than a big if statement)

Comment: Matt: Did you mean to @Jack instead of me?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
 .... here you have c1 and c2. compare returns -1 if c1 should go before c2,
 0 if they are found to be equal, and 1 if c2 should go before c1.
 You add the logic to compare c1 and c2 fields as you stated and return the result.
 }

 }
```

Then you use Collections.sort to sort that list using this comparator.

Comment: could you please show it in code terms by making the comparator class only

Answer (score 0):

You can help of the below code.

```
import java.util.*;

class Customer {

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String forename;

    public Customer(int age, String surname, String forename) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
        this.name = surname;
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    public String getForename() {
        return forename;
    }
}

class AgeComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object emp1, Object emp2) {

        int emp1Age = ((Customer) emp1).getAge();
        int emp2Age = ((Customer) emp2).getAge();

        if (emp1Age > emp2Age)
            return 1;
        else if (emp1Age < emp2Age)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}

/*
 * The below given comparator compares employees on the basis of their name.
 */

class NameComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object emp1, Object emp2) {

        // parameter are of type Object, so we have to downcast it to Employee
        // objects

        int emp1Age = ((Customer) emp1).getAge();
        int emp2Age = ((Customer) emp2).getAge();

        if (emp1Age > emp2Age) {
            return 1;
        } else if (emp1Age < emp2Age) {
            String emp1Name = ((Customer) emp1).getName();
            String emp2Name = ((Customer) emp2).getName();

            // uses compareTo method of String class to compare names of the
            // employee
            return emp1Name.compareTo(emp2Name);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}

class CustomerComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object emp1, Object emp2) {

        // parameter are of type Object, so we have to downcast it to Employee
        // objects

        String emp1Name = ((Customer) emp1).getName();
        String emp2Name = ((Customer) emp2).getName();

        // uses compareTo method of String class to compare names of the
        // employee
        return emp1Name.compareTo(emp2Name);

    }

}

public class JavaComparatorExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Employee array which will hold employees
        Customer employee[] = new Customer[3];

        // set different attributes of the individual employee.
        employee[0] = new Customer(46, "Alabama", "Christonson");
        employee[1] = new Customer(21, "Anna", "Sobek");
        employee[2] = new Customer(27, "Rafael", "Sobek");

        System.out.println("Order of employee before sorting is");
        // print array as is.
        for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Employee " + (i + 1) + " name :: "
                    + employee[i].getName() + ", Age :: "
                    + employee[i].getAge());
        }

        Arrays.sort(employee, new AgeComparator());
        System.out
                .println("\n\nOrder of employee after sorting by employee age is");

        for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Employee " + (i + 1) + " name :: "
                    + employee[i].getName() + ", Age :: "
                    + employee[i].getAge());
        }

        // Sorting array on the basis of employee Name by passing NameComparator
        Arrays.sort(employee, new NameComparator());

        System.out
                .println("\n\nOrder of employee after sorting by employee name is");
        for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Employee " + (i + 1) + " name :: "
                    + employee[i].getName() + ", Age :: "
                    + employee[i].getAge());
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this will help you.

**EDIT**

Look at the `CustomerComparator`  class.

Comment: you haven't understood my query

Comment: Oh no. Then what is problem ?I couldn't understand though I develop the code.

Comment: I want only one comparator not two seprate comparators Man

Comment: Then you will have to decide the priority that what you have to compare. Name or Age ?

Comment: Want age first and then name Man..!!

Comment: The you can cobine the `Comparator` class `AgeComparator` and `NameComparator` and first compare Age and then compare name in the `compare` method. and Pass `Customer` object as argument in that method.

Comment: I think this is the best solution which can help you

Comment: could you Please show it in code terms so that will be a great help to understand

Comment: @Bhavnik so what happened no reply from your side

Comment: I have edited the code. You can see the code above. I have created one another class `CustomerComparator` where I have defined the logic of comparing the customer. You can also edit the method as per you requirement.

Comment: @Bhavik...lOGIC SHOULD BE SOME THING LIKE THAT i HAVE EDITED ABOVE

Comment: will `CustomerComparator` will not help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
  int r = Integer.valueOf(c1.getAge()).compareTo(c2.getAge());
  if (r != 0) return r;
  r = c1.getSurname().compareTo(c2.getSurname());
  if (r != 0) return r;
  return c1.getForename().compareTo(c2.getForename());
}
```